# Issues with css3 animation on text

Tags: html, css

i'm building a website and i got some issues with a text slide animation.

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z0thg0e/)

And here is the animation part :

```
.slide {


-webkit-animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide{
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

As you can see when the text slides in, the sentence shrinks itself and it doesn't look really smooth. Can someone help me with that ?

I also have a little problem with the blue banner : It looks like it has a margin on the left of like 10px and i can't remove it.
How can i have the banner to take the entire width of the browser ?

This is my first time posting here so if i'm doing something wrong could you tell me please :)

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle .. Its showing blank output..

Comment: you have .text {margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;} in your Css. remove them if you dont want the margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your div `.text` has no `width` assigned, he tries to fit the text inside your div. You can change this by adding a `width` to your `.text`:

```
.text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Second, the `margin` you want to avoid is caused by a browser standard for your body tag. You can remove it by adding `margin: 0;` to it:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can check your working [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0z0thg0e/1/) demo. I have added a black background to demonstrate the removed margin.

Comment: Thank you ! it works now i've put the width at 95% so the text doesn't go all the way to the side of the screen.

Comment: @Kalyr thats good to hear. if the answer helped you please mark it as correct to guide following users visiting this site. if not please provider your own answer.